# Placeholder css not working in chrome after update

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I have recently updated chrome from version **39** to version **43.0.2357.132**. Before updation the following piece of code was working just fine:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

But after updating its not working. I also tried:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

But no luck! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `43.0.2357.132 m (64-bit)` here, but it works as I use your first css to create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42e4crsa/).

Comment: have you tried removing the `-webkit-` prefix?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/ - "_Important warning: this syntax is non-standard, and in flux. It will change in the near future, so don’t rely on it too heavily._"

Comment: @fuyushimoya I just dont understand, I see that its working fine in the fiddle but not in my web application.

Comment: @JamieBarker Thanks..but not working.

Comment: You should check that if you have imported some other css file that also alters that value. From the information given, we can only create that simple jsfiddle, and show it works, you have to create one that can reproduce the issue, so we can help further.

Comment: Perhaps you have some formatting problems in your CSS causing it to not work, or something that's overriding it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

Code snippets:

```
::i-block-chrome,
        input[placeholder]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: red;
        }
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue in my application where I could not get placeholder colors to work in Chrome, not even in 2018. All demos worked just fine for me, it just failed in my application despite following all regular advise, such as splitting declarations.

To make a long story short, this completely unrelated declaration in my stylesheet was causing placeholder colors to fail in Chrome:

```
input:first-line {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The above is a fairly common hack to harmonize line height inside input elements across browsers. You may find it in some frameworks.

Well, using it prevents you from setting custom colors for placeholders in Chrome. Does that make sense? No. But it solved it for me.